# Ordering and Renaming files by a certain criteria?

Tags: windows

So I have a lot of files (hundreds of them) in a folder, and I like to order them and rename them with an automated process. 
the names of those files are in a form similar to this : " Learning Java 46578.avi " and " learning python 46579.avi" and so on, the numbers on the end of each file name are successive. 
So my problem is I cant order the files alphabetically because each one starts with a different letter. What I want is to write a script that checks automatically the number at the end of the file name and order the files accordingly and/or place those number in the beginning of all file names so they can be ordered Alphabetically

I hope that my question is good

Thank you

Comment: No, it's not a good question. A good question for Stack Overflow on the topic of writing code is the one that shows what you have tried, and describes the problem with the code. If you're not interested in at least trying to solve the problem yourself, simply use Advanced Renamer or similar utility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the regex for replacing "123456-name" pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756786/what-is-the-regex-for-replacing-123456-name-pattern)

Comment: Actually I've never coded anything in powershell i'm totally new, I just wanted to know if this was possible so I can try it as I'm learning, Thank you for your help

Comment: PowerShell allows to do almost anything, especially with the files, so it's 100 times faster to check what's possible by googling for "how to do something in powershell". Since the language exists for many years there are lots of tutorials and examples in search results right on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this renames the file so the numbers are in front:

```
gci C:\path\*.avi | % {if($_.Name -match "([a-zA-Z ]+) ([0-9]+).avi"){Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$($Matches[2]) $($Matches[1]).avi"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing alphabetical (by order of letters in the alphabet) and numerical (number value) sorting. You *can* order them alphabetically because they start with a different letter, if you put the number at the beginning they *can't* be sorted alphabetically (as easily).

> What I want is to write a script that checks automatically the number at the end of the file name and order the files accordingly

You can't "order the files" on-disk, but you can *show them* in a different order. PowerShell lets you calculate a value for each thing in the pipeline and then order them by that value. You can strip out the last number, make it an [int] and then sort the files by that to display them:

```
# This sorts files by the numeric value of "the last number in the filename"

Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property { $_.Name -match '(\d+)[^\d]*$'; [int]$Matches[1] }
```

Note that if you rename them to put the number first, you risk "number stored as string" sorting like 1,11,100,2,22,200.  Windows Explorer handles sorting and displaying by numeric value, but that's not necessarily the case for all programs which list filenames.